# Deleting django form field help_text after errors are shown

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm trying to delete the password help texts once a form is being re-rendered with errors. For some reason, it keeps recreating the help_text before the form is rendered.

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm, SetPasswordForm


# Helper function used to switch the password help texts
# So that it appears under the second password instead of the first
def switchHelpTexts(form):
    ### This works ###
    help_text = form.fields["password1"].help_text
    form.fields["password1"].help_text = None
    form.fields["password2"].help_text = help_text
    ### This works ###


# Helper function used to delete the password help texts
# when validation errors are displayed. We don't need the same info twice
def deleteHelpTexts(form):
    ### This doesn't work ###
    form.fields["password1"].help_text = None
    form.fields["password2"].help_text = None
    ### This doesn't work ###

class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    field_order = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        switchHelpTexts(self)

        # # Commented out because deleteHelpTexts doesn't work for some reason
        # if self.errors and (self.errors.keys() & {"password1", "password2"}):
        #     deleteHelpTexts(self)
```

Even more surprising, if I do this:

```
def deleteHelpTexts(form):
    form.fields["password1"].help_text = None
    form.fields["password2"].help_text = "Hello"
    print(form.fields["password2"].help_text)
```

the console prints "Hello" like it's supposed to, but the form still re-renders with the original helptext instead of "Hello"